# loop through json response object with python

Tags: python, json, django, api, python-requests

I'm trying to loop through a json response object that contains data. I would like to loop thought the json object and extract the 
for keys `event-id`, `market-id`, and `event-participant-name`. The json response is as below

```
[{
  "TIMESTAMP": "2018-09-05 22: 59: 44.398534 ",
  "id": 900652866170042,
  "name": "C Suarez Navarro vs M Keys",
  "sport-id": 9,
  "start": "2018-09-05T23:10:00.000Z",
  "in-running-flag": false,
  "allow-live-betting": true,
  "category-id": [
    9,
    399952692940010,
    410468520880009,
    573630974180009,
    613128376040013,
    643136938410012,
    894084819950041
  ],
  "status": "open",
  "volume": 83821.22796,
  "event-participants": [{
      "id": 900652866280041,
      "event-id": 900652866170042,
      "participant-name": "C Suarez Navarro",
      "number": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 900652866290042,
      "event-id": 900652866170042,
      "participant-name": "M Keys",
      "number": 2
    }
  ],
  "markets": [{
        "live": false,
        "event-id": 900652866170042,
        "id": 900652866490041,
        "name": "Moneyline",
        "runners": [{
              "withdrawn": false,
              "prices": [{
                  "available-amount": 1390.32516,
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                  "odds": 3.44,
                  "decimal-odds": 3.44,
                  "side": "back",
                  "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                },
                {
                  "available-amount": 12.22,
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                  "odds": 3.36,
                  "decimal-odds": 3.36,
                  "side": "back",
                  "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                },
                {
                  "available-amount": 38.84366,
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                  "odds": 3.34,
                  "decimal-odds": 3.34,
                  "side": "back",
                  "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                },
                {
                  "available-amount": 1843.65097,
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                  "odds": 3.48,
                  "decimal-odds": 3.48,
                  "side": "lay",
                  "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                },
                {
                  "available-amount": 27.82505,
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                  "odds": 3.5,
                  "decimal-odds": 3.5,
                  "side": "lay",
                  "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                },
                {
                  "available-amount": 11.20312,
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                  "odds": 3.56,
                  "decimal-odds": 3.56,
                  "side": "lay",
                  "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                }
              ],
              "event-id": 900652866170042,
              "id": 900652866590042,
              "market-id": 900652866490041,
              "name": "C Suarez Navarro",
              "status": "open",
              "volume": 25342.31304,
              "event-participant-id": 900652866280041
            },
            {
              "withdrawn": false,
              "prices": [{
                    "available-amount": 4572.25441,
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                    "odds": 1.40322,
                    "decimal-odds": 1.40322,
                    "side": "back",
                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                  },
                  {
                    "available-amount": 69.56263,
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                    "odds": 1.4,
                    "decimal-odds": 1.4,
                    "side": "back",
                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                  },
```

When I loop thought this JSON object I get a key error. How do I loop though this object and return every value for each attribute?

Code

```
def match_book_get(self):

   tennis_events = self.api.market_data.get_events(sport_ids= 
   [9],states=MarketStates.All, per_page=10000, offset=0,
                                include_event_participants=Boolean.T, 
   price_depth=3, side=Side.All)

   data = []

   for data in tennis_events:
       event_id = data['event_id']
       market_id = data['market-id']
       evparid = data['event-participant-id']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from the JSON response, the keys you are looking for are located in a list under the `markets` and `runners` keys. You should use something like the following:

```
for data in tennis_events:
    for market in data['markets']:
       event_id = market['event-id']
       for runner in market['runners']:
           market_id = runner['market-id']
           evparid = runner['event-participant-id']
```

Comment: You should use a dash instead of an underscore (i.e. `event-id` instead of `event_id`)

Comment: Cheers that worked. I'm getting a keyerror on   event-participant-id I'm not sure why? would it be in a different section of the json object?

Comment: You posted an incomplete JSON response but maybe not every `runner` block has an `event-participant-id`?

Comment: Here's the gist to the full json. It's really weird since you say that some runner blocks has event-paricipant-id and some don't 
https://gist.github.com/Hey-tom/46f96552439b084f9efdc6239cf23084

Comment: It looks like that is your problem. If you can substitute a default value when there is none, you can use `runner.get('event-participant-id', 'my_default_value')` to prevent exceptions.

Comment: thanks very much for your help!! I wouldn't of been able to overcome this conundrum without your expertise!